# Why $\Bbb E\{ \log_2(1+x)\} \approx \log_2(1+\Bbb E(x))$?

Tags: probability, optimization

$\Bbb E\{ \log_2(1+x)\}  \approx \log_2(1+\Bbb E(x))$ ,where $\Bbb E$ is the notation of expectation. We think when $x$ is small or big enough, so the function $\log_2(1+x)$ seems to be linear, so the expectation and the function $log$ would change the order of calculation? I 'm confused about that. Any comments would appreciated!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, this is just an implication of Taylor's expansion. If $x$ is small

$$\ln\left(1+x\right)\approx x$$

and therefore

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\ln\left(1+x\right)\right]\approx\mathbb{E}\left[x\right]\approx\ln\left(1+\mathbb{E}\left[x\right]\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb E\{ \log_2(1+x)\} &= \int p(x)\log_2(1+x)\,dx \text{ where } p(x) \text{ is some probability density function}\\
&= \log_2(\int (1+x)^{p(x)}\,dx)\\
&\approx \log_2(1+\int p(x)\cdot x\,dx) \text{ with the binomial expansion}\\
&=\log_2\big(1+\mathbb{E}(x)\big)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Do a Taylor series around $E(x)$, that is 
$\mathbb{E}[\log(x)]\approx\log({E}[x])-\frac{{V}[x]}{2{E}[x]^2} \>$ according to this [paper](http://%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D[%5Clog(x)]%5Capprox%5Clog(%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D[x])-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathbb%7BV%7D[x]%7D%7B2%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D[x]%5E2%7D%20%5C%3E.). Do the same thing for $\log(1+x)$ that is
$${E}[\log(1+x)]\approx\log(1+{E}[x])-\frac{\mathbb{V}[x]}{2(1+{E}[x])^2} \>.$$